# PC doesn't start almost every time

Tags: boot, setup

1. Motherboard ASRock H110M-HDV R3.0
2. CPU Intel G4600
3. RAM DDR4 Kingston HyperX 8GB 2400MHz CL15 (2x4GB)
4. PSU Silentium 500 W Vero L2 80+ Bronze
5. HDD Toshiba P300 1TB 7200rpm 64MB

All components are new.
When I push the power button CPU fan runs but after few seconds it stops and another attempt to turn it on results in a lack of any reaction.
From time to time I am able to start the computer and it works correctly (doesn't turn off).

The motherboard supports DDR4 2133MHz but I have currently DDR4 2400MHz so I suspect that RAM should be replaced to 2133MHz.
However on the other hand all versions have 1.2V.

Should I suspect memory?

Answer (score 0):

**Your RAM will run at 2133 MHz, highest frequency supported by the motherboard, thats fine.**

The problem will either be with your **PSU** (*chances are low since its new, but can happen, test it with a tester or with another computer to be 100% sure its working fine*) **OR** with your **power button and its connection to the motherboard.**

Check the front panel connection on the motherboard (*unplug everything, except the power buttons cable to make sure*), then power on your machine.

If it fails, **unplug the power buttons cable**, and try to jump start the motherboard with a screwdriver. To do that, **bridge those two pins** with the screwdriver, but those two only!

[image]

If you succeed, then your power button + cable is faulty. If it wont start up, then you missed the pins.

Comment: Unfortunately method with a screwdriver causes the same effect. I noticed that I can turn it on for a few seconds only when the PSU power was turned off in a while but this doesn't work everytime. When I mounted motherboard I felt that the bottom part was sticky so I think there is something wrong with it.